# Module pattern context issue

Tags: javascript

How to access private variable "state" in the delete confirmation function. The "this" keyword points me to the window object.

```js
var usersController = (function() {
  var state = {},

    init = function(defaultState) {
      state = defaultState;

      $(".btn-delete-row").on("click", function() {
        var recordId = $(this).attr("data-record-id");
        showDeleteConfirmation(recordId);
      });
    },

    showDeleteConfirmation = function(recordId) {
      //how to access state private variable here???
    };

  return {
    init: init
  };
}());
```

and I call it like this:

```
$(function() {
  usersController.init({
    urls: {
      deleteRecord: "...."
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: If I try to access state in the showDeleteConfirmation I get "ReferenceError: state is not defined"

Comment: Why is there a comma after `var state = {}`?

Comment: Because state, init and showDeleteConfirmation are comma separated variables. (members and functions)

Comment: works fine here accessing `state` https://jsfiddle.net/vqdcgyyz/

Comment: I don't see why it would work in `init` but not `showDeleteConfirmation`. Is it working in `init`?

Comment: how do you access that variable? Did I get you right that you're trying to do it like `this.state`? I understand that's wrong but think that needs to be clarified:)

Comment: I simply use "state" to access it. I mentioned above what happens if I use "this.state".

Comment: Weird thing, i stopped inside "showDeleteConfirmation" with "debugger" and I could not access "state" but if I put an alert there, I can access the variable.

Comment: @charlietfl  Please move your comment inside an answer so i can accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `state` is available anywhere inside `usersController`

Try:

```
showDeleteConfirmation = function(recordId) {
      console.log(state);
};
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vqdcgyyz/)**</kbd>